# Messages android database

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. У меня идет обмен данными между юзерами приложения через сервер. Нужно сделать обмен сообщениями между пользователями, я не понимаю как это сделать. Мне предлагали xmpp, но чего-то в нем трудно разобраться. А можно ли как-то сделать по-другому обмен сообщениями, не обязательно instant messaging. Как это сделать с помощью сервера я не понимаю какую таблицу в базе данных строить. благодарю.

ясное дело что буду хранить сообщения в базе девайса пользователя, но надо их как-то передавать эти сообщения. я думаю построить таблицу "сообщения" с полями "ид" "получатель", "отправитель" и "сообщение" при каждом новом сообщении добавлять в таблицу. а на девайсе сделать сервис который будет через каждый определенный интервал времени проверять если есть новые сообщения для данного пользователя. так нормально? мне кажется что можно как-то по умнее сделать.

Comment: мне кажется, вы не понимаете на много больше, чем "какую таблицу в базе данных строить". Таблица в базе не будет отправлять и принимать сообщения сама.

Comment: metalurgus, у меня апи написано на php. отправляю данные через http post json -ом. понятно что база сама не будет ничего делать. я написал свой вариант как я думаю это реализовать. посмотрите.

Comment: при помощи Push Notifications можно сделать это все без дергания сервера. А как сохранять сообщения на сервере - вопрос на любителя. Вряд ли на что-то повлияет.